# Multithreaded application at boot sequence - C++/Debian

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boot, autostart

I'm having this obscure problem since 2 days : I created a launch-at-boot application in C++ on a debian system, which worked flawlessly until I integrated some multithreading elements.

- There are only 2 threads (1 main and 1 child)
- I included -lpthread and -pthread in the makefile
- I tried both /.config/autostart and the .desktop file methods (same
  result)
- The program is lanched with sudo
- There is no error/crash anywhere, the main thread works OK, but the
  child thread runs 1 iteration only then stops for some reason
- even tried to add some sleep in the lxsession boot sequence
- If I launch the same command line than in the autostart file in a terminal (sudo or not), it works perfectly.

Its been 2 days and I just have NO CLUE ! 
If someone experienced this before or can find some logic in it, i'll be ever grateful.

Comment: Are you forgetting to check any error codes? Is the thread stopping or exiting?

Comment: Really nothing comes out of the terminal. It just runs. Is there any other place to see error codes ?

Comment: @Binarynam Does your program run correctly when it's not launched at boot?

Comment: If you launch with `sudo` and rely on a desktop session to auto-login and perform desktop autostarts, *you are doing it wrong!* What you have there is a service and you should start it as such, i.e. create a systemd service file (or if not using systemd an init script). **Never** start GUI applications with sudo! Doing that rips apart the security of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.

I found a "fix" : running the startup program in a terminal ('@lxterminal -e *url/to/program &*' in autostart of lxsession) instead of background seems to fix it SOMEHOW. There is no GUI though ... it is a service.

The multithreaded logic isnt at fault here, not my first shot, and I really want to keep this feature (@Mike Robinson).

I will reconsider the use of sudo as suggested as well, which seems sketchy all things considered. It might get it running in background. thanks @ datenwolf.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you simply have ... *a bug* in your new logic.  You have made an error in the design of your multi-threading logic, such that the child thread only runs one iteration.  (Or, much more likely, *stalls* in an infinite-wait. Waits for a event that is never signaled, a semaphore that is never raised, a queue that runs dry and is never filled, and so on.)

We can help you further if you post excerpts of the code in question ... only illustrating *how* the child thread is launched and how it interacts with the parent.  (Condition-variables, semaphores, and so-forth, which is probably where the crux of your error lies.)

I would suggest that "all the other stuff is irrelevant."  You don't need "a sleep in the boot-sequence" (if the sequence waits for your program to complete, *and* if it needs to). I suggest that it seems to me that you simply have ... a **bug** in your new code which introduces multi-threading.

And you might wish to contemplate whether multi-threading is advantageous, given that you had a non-threaded version of the same thing that worked properly. If the processing that is to be done used to be done (successfully) by a single thread, such processing might or might not be more-advantageously processed by *"n* threads." *Should* you find-and-fix this bug, or is it just as well to abandon the change and revert back to what worked? Only you can decide that ...